# Turn off grid in a loglog graph with multiple axes

Tags: matplotlib

I want to draw a graph with two y scales and a loglog graph in it. I followed the example given [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html):

Now, I want to turn off the grid, because it looks quite ugly if I print it on a small paper. However, the grid just does not vanish! If I do this using a non-logarithmic scale, everything is OK, but this somehow doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
ax1.loglog(t, s1)
plt.hold(False)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [grid function](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid)`ax1.grid(b=False)`

Comment: Is there any way to get the current state of the grid? I mean I would like to `ax1.grid(b!=b)` functionality.

Comment: I don't think so. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246021/matplotlib-check-if-grid-is-on).

Comment: calling ``ax.grid()`` is what you're asking for @arbulgazar. It's as if ``ax1.grid(b!=b)`` were a thing.

Answer (score 0):

`fig = plt.subplots(m, n, subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []}) # m_by_n grid`

Comment: A little explanation about your code would improve your answer drastically.

Answer (score 0):

In the v1.5.3 [documentation on axis_api](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html) the following is stated:

> `grid(self, b=None, which='major', axis='both', **kwargs)`
>
> Set the axes grids on or off; *b* is a boolean.  (For MATLAB
>   compatibility, *b* may also be a string, 'on' or 'off'.)
>
> If *b* is *None* and `len(kwargs)==0`, toggle the grid state.  If
>   *kwargs* are supplied, it is assumed that you want a grid and *b* is thus set to *True*.

In other words, calling `ax.grid()` should toggle the grid on and off without the need to know the existing state. (To answer arbulgazar's question above. I'm below 50 reputation so can't reply with comment.)